# Error using mismatched PostCSS dependencies

Tags: npm, dependencies, gatsby, css-modules

Anyone know how to get composes working in gatsby css modules. 
I've tried using.

```
.dog {
  composes: dog from "styles/common.scss"
}
```

I get this error.

> Your current PostCSS version is 5.2.18, but postcss-nesting uses
>   6.0.23. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.

I've tried installing [postcss-nesting](http://%20https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-nesting) 
But that doesn't seem to stop the above error in gatsby

Answer (score 0):

Your current PostCSS version is 5.2.18, but postcss-nesting uses 6.0.23. Perhaps this is the source of the error you're running into.

Try upgrading PostCSS to at least 6.0

Comment: Yea thats what I thought but thats controlled from gatsby. Its not an npm update. Not sure how to do that without updating gatsby itself ?

Comment: Which version of Gatsby are you on? Where are the nested dependencies on `postcss-nesting` and `postcss` coming from?

Comment: Gatsby Version 1.1.58, Not sure what you mean by your second question. Scss is where I'm nesting css and want to use compose

Comment: Okay, you may want to update your Gatsby to the latest stable (1.9.x) to see if that helps. Re: Nested dependencies, please read up on the package manager you're using (yarn or npm).

Comment: Ok I'll try that. postcss-nesting is not been used. I tried installing it up it didn't fix the issue. I'll try upgrading.

Comment: I also tried searching Gatsby docs about Gatsby Version 1.1.58 not compatible with compose but didn't find anything. Would love to know for sure if its not compatible.

Comment: What should be the latest version # when I run gatsby --version ?